# How to combine two separate aggregations together in same result in mongodb with join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two different aggregate collections, in the first collection I simply retrieve data from mongo collection, and in the second collection I retrieve date from 3 collection using joins (lookup, match) and groups.

Now I want to apply join on first and second collection using MongoDB
eg.

```
select a1.name , a2.count
from (select * from a where xyz group by name) as a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select * from b(this contains multiple table joins)) as a2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Pravin.

As MongoDB documentation [states](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-DBRef), it is most useful in cases where your data model is denormalized (i.e. related data is stored within a single document).

- So your first solution is to design your schema in a way that would
  help you avoid making complex join queries.
- You also have an option to make two separate queries to the database
  and use [Manual references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references), like foreign keys in RDBMS.
- You also have an option to use so-called [DBrefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation)

Depending on your particular task one of these options may be applicable